# Foundation 5: Change Container color behind Tabs & Tab Content Panels

Tags: html, css

I am working on building a web app using Foundation 5 as the framework. I have a page which contains a comments and updates section, navigated by tabs and contained within panels.

I successfully added a box shadow to the tab content panels that contain the updates and comments, but now there are margins on either side with white space that don't blend with the styling of the rest of the page.

I used inspect element too look at at what element the margins fall into, and they are part of the content panels themselves. How would I go about changing the background so that the margins blend with the rest of the page, and the tabs & content are white with a box shadow?

The html for the tab and accompanying panels is as follows:

```
<div id ="tabs">
<ul class="tabs" data-tab role="tablist">
<li class="tab-title active" role="presentational" ><a href="#panel2-1"       role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" controls="panel2-1">Updates</a></li>
<li class="tab-title" role="presentational" ><a href="#panel2-2" role="tab" tabindex="0"aria-selected="false" controls="panel2-2">Comments</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="tabs-content">
<section role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" class="content active"  id="panel2-1">
```

I use the following css to make the box-shadow around the panels and tabs:

```
section#panel2-1.content.active {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px;
margin-left: 50px;
width: 1050px;

}

section#panel2-2.content.active {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px;
margin-left: 50px;
width: 1050px;

}
```

I tried adding a div around the tabs and content panel so I could change the background color, but it didn't have an effect.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks,

Matti

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using these Sass variables to override the default styles?

```
$include-html-tabs-classes: $include-html-classes;

$tabs-navigation-padding: rem-calc(16);
$tabs-navigation-bg-color: $silver;
$tabs-navigation-active-bg-color: $white;
$tabs-navigation-hover-bg-color: scale-color($tabs-navigation-bg-color, $lightness: -6%);
$tabs-navigation-font-color: $jet;
$tabs-navigation-active-font-color: $tabs-navigation-font-color;
$tabs-navigation-font-size: rem-calc(16);
$tabs-navigation-font-family: $body-font-family;

$tabs-content-margin-bottom: rem-calc(24);
$tabs-content-padding: $column-gutter/2;

$tabs-vertical-navigation-margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
```